# How to send FCM push notification message from app server to mobile clients?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have already developed a simple application for both iOS and android. Now i want to implement push notification services for both apps. So I would like to implement FCM(Firebase cloud messaging.) service for sending push notifications.I read the google docs but have some doubts. My app server have all my users data. I want to send notification to single, multiple and all users from my app server based on needs.
FCM Tokens are needed to send push notifications from app server to mobile clients? What are the things to do in both mobile and server side? Can't find clear ideas.

FCM is only for intermediate to send push notification message? 
Do we need to store any user details in Firebase? Because all of my users data in app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your situation, Firebase Console would be fine for sending notifications to both your iOS and Android application.
After configuring your application with firebase cloud messaging you are able to send notifications.

for your other doubt if any user download your application or update with the new build integrated with Firebase Cloud messaging, they will receive notifications.
 FCM gives you option to send Single(via : device token for specific iPhone) or to all users who had downloaded the application with FCM integration.

**so you don’t need to store any user data on your server !**

for “**How can you send notifications** “ you can check these references : -

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client - Google Firebase Docs

https://codentrick.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-ios/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBw5tuTvKd4 - swift

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsWHzU1DxjM - Objective c

and with firebase you can integrate 
Cloud Firestore,
ML Kit ,
Cloud Functions,
Authentications,
Analytics,
cloud storage,
Hosting,
Realtime database.